# How to switch an Hibernate many-to-many relationship from xml to annotation based configuration?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

```
<set name="Units" table="UNIT" mutable="false">
        <cache usage="read-only"/>
        <key column="ID"></key>
        <many-to-many column="U_ID" class="com.org.Unit"/>
```

I have declared variable in `Supplier.java` as:

```
private Set <Unit> Units;
```

Comment: private Set<Unit> Units;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your entity class `Supplier` put:

```
private Set<Unit> units;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="UNIT", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID")}, 
           inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="U_ID")}
)
public Set<Unit> getUnits() {
    return units;
}
```

Comment: <set name="Units" table="UNIT" mutable="false"> , shall "UNIT" will be the table name?

Comment: ops, sorry, I haven't noticed the name. Yes, I'm gonna edit my answer.